# Can Torah scrolls be stored in drawers laying horizontally?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, ark-aron-kodesh

All arks that I have seen have the Torah scrolls stored standing vertically in the ark.

Is this an absolute halachic requirement that the Torah must be stored vertically? What if an ark contained a series of drawers such that each Torah were stored in its own drawer, or lets say one large drawer could hold several Torah scrolls, and you could store 2 or 3 laying flatly next to each other. Are there any halachic problems with storing Torah scrolls flatly?

Comment: I recall here seeing that it's a machloket rishonim between Rashi and R"T. One says vertical, the other horizontal; thus we store them at a slight angle.

Comment: I think in Belz they do that

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%96_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%96

Comment: רון הקודש המפואר שוקל כ-23 טון, גובהו 12 מטר ורוחבו כ-8 מטר. הוא עשוי מעץ שהובא מברזיל. 70 ספרי תורה מונחים בארון בשכיבה ולא בעמידה כמקובל, וזאת על פי שיטת רבנו תם. על פי המסורת החסידית האדמו"ר הראשון של החסידות, רבי שלום רוקח, היה "ניצוץ נשמת רבנו תם", ומאז נהגו כך בבתי הכנסת של אדמו"רי בעלז (אך לא בשאר בתי הכנסיות והמדרשות של החסידות).‏[1]

Comment: @cham please translate

Comment: "The famous Ark weighs 23 tons, is 12 meters tall, and is about 8 meters wide. It's made from wood imported from Brazil. 70 Torah scrolls are placed in the Ark, lying down and not standing as is their custom, according to the opinion of Rabbeinu Tam....." @cham's quote describes the Belz synagogue in Jerusalem, but I'm not sure where the quote originates. (It doesn't either cite where one can find this quoted opinion of R"T, but is consistent with what I've heard about that synagogue)